# managing multiple user specific dbadapter with Zend_Db_Table

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

I have a very quick question about how to utilise Zend_Db_Table with user specific database adapters.

I have an application that has a meta table that contains all application data, such as user logins, lookup tables and the like.  Each client has then it's own database for their data.

I have in my Zend Project in the model folder another folder called meta.  All Zend_Db_Tables that are used for the application are stored here.  All Zend_Db_Table objects that interact with the clients database are in the models folder direct.

```
  /application
  |
  |models/
  |- UserTable.php
  |- AnotherTable.php
  |- meta/
  |- - LookupTable1.php
  |- - LoginTable.php
```

What is the best way of injecting the user dbadapter, which contains the client database connection, into all the Zend_Db_Table object that sit in the modles folder but not in the meta sub folder?

The meta tables need to be accessable throughout the application, so changing the default adapter in the Zend_Registry won't work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Grant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$userTable = new Model_DbTable_Users(array('db'=>$dbadapter));
```

another way

```
$userTable = new Model_DbTable_Users();
$userTable->setDefaultAdapter($dbadapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe have two different subclasses of Zend_Db_Table and set the different Db adaptor for each. Then your models subclass one and your meta tables, the other?